# Anderson Darling exponential distribution

Tags: goodness-of-fit

I need a goodness of fit test for the exponential distribution.  I understand that Kolmogorov-Smirnov is not generally regarded as very powerful and that Anderson-Darling is regarded as superior. However I have two problems.

- None of the literature I can find specifically talks about goodness of fit for exponential distributions.  Anderson-Darling is almost always discussed wrt the normal distribution.
- Is there an R (or python) package to do an Anderson-Darling goodness of fit for the exponential distribution? I can find them for other distributions.
- Is there  a better test (which exists in R or python)?

Comment: Is this a completeley specified distribution or are we estimating parameters?

Comment: @Glen_b In some case I will have to estimate the parameters which I know causes another problem. A method which had a correction factor for that case would be even better of course!

Comment: When you say A-D's more powerful than K-S, what kind of departures from exponentiality are you thinking of?

Comment: @Scortchi I am thinking for example if the tail is too long.  A test just for that case would be great.

Comment: I'd guess the LRT for Weibull shape parameter less than one would have good power against long tailed alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same considerations apply as to the distribution of the  Kolmogorov–Smirnov test statistic discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110272/a-naive-question-about-the-kolmogorov-smirnov-test). The Anderson–Darling test statistic (for a given sample size) has a distribution that (1) doesn't depend on the null-hypothesis distribution when all parameters are known, & (2) depends only on the functional form of the null-hypothesis distribution when location & scale parameters are estimated. I don't know of an R implementation of the A–D test specifically for the exponential distribution with estimated rate parameter, but you could quickly make a function to calculate the test statistic by adapting the `ad.test` function from the `nortest` package: change the distribution function from  the best-fit normal, `pnorm((x - mean(x))/sd(x))`, to the best-fit exponential,`pexp(x/mean(x))`. Then get critical values for any desired significance level & sample size by simulation.

As to the "best" test, note that different tests are more powerful against different kinds of departure from the null-hypothesis distribution. If you have a quite specific alternative in mind, e.g. a Weibull distribution with shape parameter greater than one, a likelihood ratio test will be more powerful than a general-purpose goodness-of-fit test. For more vaguely specified alternatives it might be helpful to compare the power of various tests against a rogues gallery, following the approach of Stephens (1974), "EDF statistics for goodness of fit and some comparisons", *JASA*, **69**, 347.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't even find an implementation of the A-D test for the exponential distribution with known rate parameter.  I am sorry if this is obvious but are you saying nortest can be used in that case somehow?

Comment: I'm saying that rather than write a function to calculate the A-D statistic from scratch, you can modify the code used in `ad.test`. (Type `ad.test` to see it.)

Comment: @Scortchi, how did you know to change `pnorm((x - mean(x))/sd(x))` for a normal distribution to `pexp(x/mean(x))` for an exponential distribution? I am looking to test `weibull` and `lognormal` distributions thorough the AD statistic

Comment: @lukeg: I just substituted a standardized exponential variate for a standardized normal variate, &  the exponential for the normal distribution function. NB (1) If you're estimating the *shape* of a Weibull distribution as well as the scale, you need to simulate the distribution of the test statistic under your estimated parameters, & results are approximate; (2) the logarithm of a log-normal random variate has a normal distribution.